# 3rd image (with identical classes/properties as 1st 2) sizing differently

Tags: html, css, image

The images I'm referencing can be seen here:

I have a Wordpress custom field/layout that uses a standard Features box setup to display 3 boxes side by side that will link to 3 different menus. All 3 (including the divs that contain them) have the same classes assigned. And despite the "grid" terminology sprinkled through all the CSS classes, there is no CSS grid or flexbox being used in this section. Each image file is also the same dimensions.

At first I thought it was an issue with the third image just getting pushed down by the first two and then stretching itself a little to fill some available space, but if you shrink the window to mobile size, the third image still retains different proportions. This is also true when I set the containing parent div to a max-width of 30%. All 3 images show up on the same line, but the third one is still wider than it is tall.

Any ideas as to why this third image is going rogue?

(Note: When I add a 4th box to the layout, it shows up in a new row below the rogue box, but sized and proportioned like the first 2.)

```css
/**/
/* menus grid */
/**/
.menus-grid {
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 4rem;
 text-align: center;
}
.menus-grid__head {
 margin: 0 auto 2rem;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2.4rem;
 line-height: 1.125;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.025em;
}
.menus-grid__item {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.menus-grid__item img {
 vertical-align: top;
}
.menus-grid__title {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 280px;
 padding: 1rem 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.625rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.025em;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.menus-grid__details {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%; /*changed from 50% to 45% for better button spacing*/
 right: 1.25rem;
 left: 1.25rem;
 opacity: 1; /*changed from 0 to 1 to enable button to appear by default*/
 /*transform: translateY(-50%); removing for menu page */
 transition-duration: 0.25s;
 transition-property: opacity;
}
.menus-grid__details h3 {
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.625rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.025em;
 opacity: 0;
 transition-duration: 0.25s;
 transition-property: opacity;
}
.menus-grid__details img {
 margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
.menus-grid__button {
 margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
.menus-grid__item:hover .menus-grid__title {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 20rem rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
 color: transparent;
}
.menus-grid__item:hover .menus-grid__details h3 {
 opacity: 1;
}
.menus-grid__circles {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 8rem;
 left: 50%;
 width: 626px;
 height: 626px;
 margin-left: 8rem;
 background: url(../img/menus-gallery/circles.png);
 pointer-events: none;
}
.menus-grid__circles_b {
 top: auto;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: -25rem;
 left: auto;
 margin: 0 12.5rem 0 0;
}
.menus-grid__circles_c {
 top: -100px;
}

.button, .field-wrap input[type="button"] {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #789904;
    background-color: #789904;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) { /* tablet */
 .menus-grid__item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) { /* mobile */
 .menus-grid__details {
  display: none;
 }
 .menus-grid__item:hover .menus-grid__title {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: inherit;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="menus-grid">
    <div data-wow-duration="5s" class="menus-grid__circles wow rotateIn"> </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <h2 class="menus-grid__head">Menus</h2>
        <div class="grid-row">
            <div class="grid-col">
                <div class="menus-grid__item">
                    <img src="https://foodbytano.com/1556655652339/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/1_Brunch_500x660px-374x358.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h3 class="menus-grid__title">Brunch</h3>
                    <div class="menus-grid__details">
                        <h3>Brunch</h3>
                        <a class="menus-grid__button button" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">View Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-col">
                <div class="menus-grid__item">
                    <img src="https://foodbytano.com/1556655652339/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2_Lunch_500x660px-374x358.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h3 class="menus-grid__title">Lunch</h3>
                    <div class="menus-grid__details">
                        <h3>Lunch</h3>
                        <a class="menus-grid__button button" href="http://www.google.com" target="">View Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-col">
                <div class="menus-grid__item">
                    <img src="https://foodbytano.com/1556655652339/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3_Dinner_500x660px-501x358.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h3 class="menus-grid__title">Dinner</h3>
                    <div class="menus-grid__details">
                        <h3>Dinner</h3>
                        <a class="menus-grid__button button" href="http://www.google.com" target="">View Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your website requires a log in and you shouldn't ask users to go to another site like this anyway.

Comment: @JuanCortés Removed link, added picture

Comment: Please add a [mcve], not a picture =))

Comment: @KoshVery Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third image is 501px wide while the others are 374px:

> 1_Brunch_500x660px-374x358.jpg
>   2_Lunch_500x660px-374x358.jpg
>   3_Dinner_500x660px-501x358.jpg

Changing the third filename to

`https://foodbytano.com/1556655652339/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3_Dinner_500x660px-374x358.jpg`

does the trick..

Comment: But that's the thing, the three image files are exactly the same size. I'm updating the original post with screenshots from my Wordpress page editor as evidence.

Comment: @ipenguin67, you can see the sizes included in the images filenames, also if you right-click them on your page and see `Image Info` you'll see that the third image is bigger in width.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I'm just baffled as to why Wordpress seemingly did this behind the scenes (reason 5,000,000 why WP is the worst...). Looking in that folder, it seems it created 6 copies of my image with varying dimensions and then decided which one to use. I know this is out of scope of the original question, but do you have any idea why it did this and how to override it?

Comment: @ipenguin67, Sorry, I have no idea why WP does this or that.. Probably its documentation has something explained.